# Is there a way to show this series diverges without calculating the value of the limit in the ratio test?

Tags: real-analysis

Take the series $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+3^k}{1+2^k}$

Now, I've proved this series diverges by applying the ratio test, and with a very long chain of calculus I got R > 1. The issue is it seems extremely long and I was wondering if there are any more efficient ways?

I'm trying to get better at avoiding using needlessly long ways of proving a series diverges / converges and I just wanted to ask for some examples.

Edit: 1 example I thought of is comparing it to the series $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+3^k}{1+3^k}$

In this case, $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+3^k}{1+2^k}$  > $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+3^k}{1+3^k}$  and $\Sigma_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1+3^k}{1+3^k}$ = 1 + 1 + 1 ... Is this valid?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, bounding the term each by $1$ from below is a valid proof.

Comment: Generally, for a series to converge it is necessary that its terms converge to zero, i.e. if $\sum a_k$ converges, then $a_k\to 0$ is necessary.

Comment: @DominikS I understand, but would I not have to outright prove that each term in my series is > or = to 1? Or is it given

Comment: In your case, this is what you did and what worked. Generally, the bound does not to be $1$, and not every term needs to be bounded away from zero (only a subsequence, for example).

Comment: In fact, each term is greater than 1. So, no need to prove anything. This series' divergence is as obvious as trying to prove that 1=1

Comment: @DominikS Okay thanks. Are these type of questions okay on maths stack exchange? I don't want to ask questions that would be frowned upon / downvoted

Comment: I think the question is appropriate here - it is good that it is not a question straight from a homework sheet, and that you have shown some own effort. If you are interested, here are some [guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) I find useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series lacks the necessary converging condition: going to $0$. More precisely:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i \ \text{ converges and } \forall \ i \geq 1 \ x_i \geq 0 \implies \lim_{i\to \infty} x_i = 0 \ .$$

For your sequence this necessary condition does not hold. Indeed, your sequence actually diverges:
$$\frac{1+3^k}{1+2^k} \ = \ \frac{3^k\left(\frac{1}{3^k}+1 \right)}{2^k\left(\frac{1}{2^k}+1 \right)} \ = \ \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k \cdot\frac{\frac{1}{3^k}+1 }{\frac{1}{2^k}+1 } \ \to \ +\infty \ \ .$$

Thus, the series does not converge.

Your reasoning on the series being $\geq 1 +1+1+\dots$ is also correct (and it is also the motivation behind the necessary condition).